# Reading an STG file created from MS ActiveSync

Tags: c#

How can I parse an [STG](http://www.filesuffix.com/extension/stg.html) (Microsoft ActiveSync Mobile Device Backup) file (created by [ActiveSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveSync))?

I have an old `.stg` file that was created from backing up an old [Windows Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Mobile) device, and I would like to write a program to read it using C#. I have tried a few things but can't get anything but garbage when I read through it. From what I can find online it is stored in Unicode format but that's about it, any posts I find talking about it are ancient and all the links are dead.

Comment: It's an ActiveSync backup file, so I expect something more than just unicode. Did you check if it's compressed?

Comment: Ohh - I have no idea if is compressed - I guess I will look into how to do that.

Comment: start by copying to file.stg.zip and try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

You can open ActiveSync `.stg` files in an archiver tool such as [7-Zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/) or [PeaZip](https://www.peazip.org). If the program does not recognize the file as an archive, you may need to rename the file to have an archive extension (e.g., `.7z`, `.gz`, `.tar`).

Answer (score 0):

With PeaZip is also possible to try to open any file extension from "Open as archive" menu entry (also available in system's context menu), without changing the file's extension.

With many format being basically variations of Deflate-compressed containers, it is worth trying.

Anyway, some formats may introduce proprietary fields (e.g. extra checksums, comments, digital signing, etc) which are out of the scope for a general-purpose archiver as PeaZip or 7-Zip.
So, while it is harmless to try to read container files as archives, it is not adviceable to try to edit them as such.